# Check if object is in list given by pyshark

Tags: python, list, object

I'm trying to read a pcap file using pyshark. It seems pyshark creates a list of objects, where each object
has information about each layer inside packets.

I only want to evaluate if a layer exists in the packet. Maybe someone could help me.

The list of objects "layers" is like this:

```
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <SCTP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
```

But this evaluation fails since inside the list are objects and not strings.

```
if <ETH Layer> in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
if '<ETH Layer>' in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
```

Below are my tests...

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import pyshark
>>> file = pyshark.FileCapture('C:\\files\\input.pcap')
>>> packet=file[0]
>>> layers=packet.layers
>>> layers
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <SCTP Layer>, <DATA Layer>, <SCTP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
>>> if packet.eth in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
...
Yes, Ethernet layer exists
>>>
Yes, Ethernet layer exists
>>> if '<ETH Layer>' in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
...
>>>
```

This evaluation gives correct output

```
if packet.eth in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
```

These 2 fail, since evaluate to False

```
if <ETH Layer> in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
if '<ETH Layer>' in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
```

*Update:

If I tests packet.ip, packet.eth, packet.sctp it work only if the layer ip, eth or sctp exist, if some layer doesn't exist(i.e. tcp) I get the error below.

```
>>> if packet.tcp in layers: print "Yes, Ethernet layer exists"
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyshark\packet\packet.py", line 110, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError()
AttributeError
```

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with just checking for `if packet.eth`?

Comment: Hi Turn, If I tests packet.ip, packet.eth, packet.sctp it work only if the layer ip, eth or sctp exist, if some layer doesn't exist(i.e. tcp). Please see my update. thank you.

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ETH Layer>` isn't the actual object, it is just what the `__repr__` method of the object is returning. Your Python REPL calls that to see how to print out a representation of an evaluated expression. Similarly, it might call `__str__` if you ask it to `print` the expression. Compare these:

```
>> packet.layers[0]
<ETH Layer>

>> print packet.layers[0]
Layer ETH:
    Destination: 52:54:00:12:37:02 (52:54:00:12:37:02)
    .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
    Address: 52:54:00:12:37:02 (52:54:00:12:37:02)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
    Source: 08:00:28:1d:ae:8b (08:00:28:1d:ae:8b)
    .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Address: 08:00:28:1d:ae:8b (08:00:28:1d:ae:8b)
    .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
```

But to functionally answer your question, I believe if you want to see if a layer exists in your packet you can do something like:

```
if 'eth' in packet:
    # ...
```

Comment: Excellent Turn. It seems to work. I'm new to python and pyshark equally. So when you say <if 'eth' in packet>, it searchs the string "eth" inside the packet? I'm only tryin to figure out how to print or handle the attributes for layer or packet. Thanks again.

Comment: I am honestly not exactly sure since it looks like pyshark is obscuring it's structure a little (presumably for the sake of usability), but it looks like `packet` is a dict-like object and you are testing whether it has a key `eth`.

Comment: I undertand. Thanks so much for your help Turn.